# Create a new column in Pyspark which is calculated on another available column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe as below:

```
>>> df
   Name    id
0   Tom   103
1  Jack   109
2  nick  9518
3  juli  1890
```

I want to create a ne column as **super_id** which is  i) if id is 3 digits then super_id is zero plus the first integer ii) if id is 4 digits then super id is first two integers.

```
>>> df
   Name    id super_id
0   Tom   103       01
1  Jack   109       01
2  nick  9518       95
3  juli  1890       18
```

I have the below python code for the same but not sure how to convert it into pyspark code.

```
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'],
        'id':[103, 109, 9518, 1890]}
 
# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Create super id
df['super_id'] = df.id.astype('int').astype('str').str.zfill(4).str[0:2]
```

Attempted in pyspark with error

```
df= df.withColumn('super_id', df['id'].astype('int').astype('str').str.zfill(4).str[0:2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) to do that :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("super_id", F.substring(F.lpad("id", 4, "0"), 0, 2)).show()

+-----+----+--------+
| name|  id|super_id|
+-----+----+--------+
|  Tom| 103|      01|
| jack| 109|      01|
| nick|9518|      95|
|julie|1890|      18|
+-----+----+--------+
```